# RenderedImage filling or Drawing a IMAGEVIEW

Tags: java, image-processing, javafx

I am struggling to fill my ImageView in JavaFX with the image obtained from a digital signature tablet. It always comes from RenderedImage type and I can not perform this task. Also tried to convert the RenderedImage BufferedImage, but also did not succeed. How do I? Here is my code:

```
    @Override
  public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

//  drawpane.setPrefHeight(tabletHeight);
//  drawpane.setPrefWidth(tabletWidth);
//  pnlSignature.getChildren().add(drawpane);

    JSTUTablet.addPenPressedHandler((PenPressedHandler) new DemoPenPressHandler(pnlSignature));

    zhandleSetImage();
    start();

// Here is the focus of the problem
    try {

//Here is a method that returns a BufferedImage of my obtained the device RenderedImage.
      BufferedImage buf = convertRenderedImage(JSTUTablet.getImage());

      ImageView image = new ImageView();
      image.setFitHeight(tabletHeight);
      image.setFitWidth(tabletWidth);
      ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

      ImageIO.write(buf, "png", os);
      image.setImage(new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray())));

      pnlSignature.getChildren().add(image);

    } catch (InvalidOperationException | IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }


//Method convertRenderedImage
public BufferedImage convertRenderedImage(RenderedImage img) {
  if (img instanceof BufferedImage) {
      return (BufferedImage) img;
  }
  ColorModel cm = img.getColorModel();
  int width = img.getWidth();
  int height = img.getHeight();
  WritableRaster raster = cm.createCompatibleWritableRaster(width, height);
  boolean isAlphaPremultiplied = cm.isAlphaPremultiplied();
  Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
  String[] keys = img.getPropertyNames();
  if (keys != null) {
      for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
          properties.put(keys[i], img.getProperty(keys[i]));
      }
  }
  BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(cm, raster,isAlphaPremultiplied, properties);
  img.copyData(raster);
  return result;
}
```

Regards!!!

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Do you receive a [`RenderedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/RenderedImage.html) and want to set it on an ImageView?

Comment: It looks like you have code in there to do the conversion. What is your actual question? Is your conversion code not working? Could you describe how it's failing, or share any errors or exceptions that you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem adding two methods, in this [Link](http://www.guj.com.br/35068-renderedimage-preenchendo-uma-imageview)
Thank You!

Comment: Please don't provide [link only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers), instead copy and paste the relevant portions from the link into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for

```
image.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(buf, null));
```

`SwingFXUtils` is in `javafx.embed.swing`